# Read and write to multiple json files

Tags: python, json

We have some json template files that get deployed to our prod, QA, integration, dev servers. Various fields need to be changed depending on the server being deployed to. Right now, this is done manually on a per deployment and per server basis. I'm trying to develop a quick python script that will pull the hostname of the machine and populate the key value pair as a post deployment task before starting the app.

What's the better option. The first set of `with open()` directives or the nested ones.

```
from socket import gethostname
import json


MAPPING = {
    "HOSTNAME1":    'URL1',
    'HOSTNAME2':    'URL2',
    'HOSTNAME3':    'URL3',
    'HOSTNAME4':    'URL4'
}


def main():
    HOSTNAME = gethostname()
    FILE1 = 'D:/PATH/TO/webhook-config.json.tpl'
    FILE2 = 'D:/PATH/TO/WHERE/IWANT/IT/SAVED/webhook-config.json'
    with open(FILE1, 'r') as config_tpl, open(FILE2, 'w') as config:
        cfg = json.load(config_tpl)
        cfg['WebhooksURL'] = 'http://{URL}:3000'.format(URL=MAPPING[HOSTNAME])
        config.write(json.dumps(config, indent=4))

    with open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/scripts/bgreportexec.json.tpl', 'r') as bg_tpl:
        bg = json.load(bg_tpl)
        bg['HOSTNAME_URL'] = 'https://{URL}'.format(URL=MAPPING[HOSTNAME])

        with open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/scripts/bgreportexec.json', 'w') as bg_cfg:
            bg_cfg.write(json.dumps(bg_cfg, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This question appears to be asking about general best practices, which is [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @IEatBagels A case could be made for [tag:comparative-review].

Comment: @Mast I don't disagree, but I also think the two cases are more about what's the best practice when it comes to file handling. Also, I just noticed the code is broken. In both cases, we rewrite the same content in the file stream #2 and do nothing in the stream #1